# Displaying List of Date-Sorted XML Elements as UI Text

Tags: c#, xml, linq, unity-game-engine, foreach

I have an XML document with several different sections and I need to produce a 'feed' of the most recent entries which displays as UI text in the scene. I have a method for sorting entries by date within their sections which I know works, and I've been trying to apply it to the entire document.

This is an example of the structure of the document:

```
<Document>
  <Data>3</Data>
  <Section1>
    <Type1>
      <Entry ID="1">
        <Date>09/08/2011</Date>
        <Details1>text</Details1>
      </Entry>
      <Entry ID="3">
        <Date>07/3/2012</Date>
        <Details2>text</Details2>
      </Entry>
    </Type1>
    <Type2 />
    <Type3>
      <Entry ID="2">
        <Date>08/8/2011</Date>
        <Details3>text</Details3>
        <Details4>text</Details4>
      </Entry>
    </Type3>
  </Section1>
  <Section2>
    <Type4 />
    <Type5 />
  </Section2>
    ...
</Document>
```

The problem is that, unlike in my previous method, I need to sort the date of every entry and display them as such - not in their individual sections. So far, the dates have been displaying all over the place, although I'm fairly sure that they're being sorted properly.

My code so far is as follows (the sorting method was taken from a very helpful blog post that I can't find the link to):

```
    public void Feed () {
        Debug.Log ("Feed initiated");
        // FOR SORTING AND DISPLAYING THE DATA
        XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load (Application.persistentDataPath + "/UserData/document.xml");

        var all =
            from objActs in xDocument.Element("Document").Descendants("Entry")
                let actDate = DateTime.ParseExact(objActs.Element("Date").Value,"d/M/yyyy",new CultureInfo("en-GB"))
                orderby actDate
                select objActs;

        foreach (var objActs in all.ToList())
        {
            foreach (var aa in objActs.Ancestors("Section1").Elements("Type1").Elements("Entry")) {
                Debug.Log(aa);
                feedText.text += aa.Element("Date").Value+"\n";
                feedText.text += aa.Element("Details1").Value+"\n\n";
            }
            foreach (var ab in objActs.Ancestors("Section1").Elements("Type2").Elements("Entry")) {
                Debug.Log(ab);
                feedText.text += ab.Element("Date").Value+"\n";
                feedText.text += ab.Element("Details2").Value+"\n\n";
            }
        }
    }
```

I was originally doing this using an if (objActs.parent.parent.name == Section 1) {} method, but that had exactly the same problem.

The problem appears to be with using feedText+=, especially since entries end up repeating themselves and I get the error "String too long for TextMeshGenerator. Cutting off characters". I need to format them in rects, eventually, since I'll be adding buttons in certain positions, but I imagine that using rects will also produce the same result.

Does anyone have any idea how I can get this to display properly to text?

I'm trying to display the whole document as a 'feed' in date order, so that, when displayed as text, they would appear:

Entry 2 date
Entry 2 details

Entry 1 date
Entry 1 details

Entry 3 date
Entry 3 details

At the moment, with my code, it displays as:

Entry 1 Date
Entry 1 Details

Entry 3 Date
Entry 1 details (partial - this is the point at which the string gets too long - the foreach loop isn't stopping after reading all elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the issue with the code displaying as text was due to the function being called on Update instead of on Start.

I also changed the XML format slightly so that sections and types were attributes instead of child elements. The resultant code is as below:

```
public void Feed () {
    Debug.Log ("Feed initiated");
    // FOR SORTING AND DISPLAYING THE DATA
    XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load (Application.persistentDataPath + "/UserData/document.xml");
    // Many thanks to jdweng for suggesting using the element SortedDocument
    XElement element = new XElement("SortedDocument");

    var all =
        from objActs in xDocument.Element("Document").Descendants("Data")
            let actDate = DateTime.ParseExact(objActs.Element("Date").Value,"d/M/yyyy",new CultureInfo("en-GB"))
            orderby actDate
            select objActs;

    foreach (var objActs in all.ToList())
    {
        element.Add (objActs);
    } // Foreach
    Debug.Log(element);

    foreach (XElement sortedActs in element.Descendants("Entry")) {
        if (sortedActs.Attribute("Section").Value == "Section1") {
            if (sortedActs.Attribute("Type").Value == "Type1") {
                feedText.text+=sortedActs.Element("Date").Value+"\n";
                feedText.text+=sortedActs.Element("Details").Value+"\n\n";
            }
            if (sortedActs.Attribute("Type").Value == "Type2") {
                feedText.text+=sortedActs.Element("Date").Value+"\n";
                feedText.text+=sortedActs.Element("Details").Value+"\n\n";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Messy because of the null elemenet.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input =
                "<Document>" +
                  "<Data>3</Data>" +
                  "<Section1>" +
                    "<Type1>" +
                      "<Entry ID=\"1\">" +
                        "<Date>09/8/2011</Date>" +
                        "<Details1>text</Details1>" +
                      "</Entry>" +
                      "<Entry ID=\"3\">" +
                        "<Date>07/3/2012</Date>" +
                        "<Details2>text</Details2>" +
                      "</Entry>" +
                    "</Type1>" +
                    "<Type2 />" +
                    "<Type3>" +
                      "<Entry ID=\"2\">" +
                        "<Date>08/08/2011</Date>" +
                        "<Details3>text</Details3>" +
                        "<Details4>text</Details4>" +
                      "</Entry>" +
                    "</Type3>" +
                  "</Section1>" +
                  "<Section2>" +
                    "<Type4 />" +
                    "<Type5 />" +
                  "</Section2>" +
                "</Document>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(input);

            var results = doc.Descendants().Where(s => s.Name.ToString().StartsWith("Section"))
                .Where(t => t.Descendants("Date").Count() > 0).Select(u => u.Elements().Where(v => v.Descendants("Date").Count() > 0)
                    .Select(w => w.Elements().Select(x => new
                    {
                        element = x,
                        dates = (DateTime)x.Descendants("Date").FirstOrDefault()
                    }).ToList()).SelectMany(y => y).OrderBy(z => z.dates).ToList().Select(b => b.element).ToList()).FirstOrDefault();

        }
    }

}
​
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I tried your solution in a separate script, but I couldn't get the list to display other than printing that it was a list. Also (sorry if I was a little unclear), the sections are actually named completely differently, as are the majority of the types, excluding the Date element, so I'm not sure the StartsWith approach would work. I tried results.ForEach(Debug.Log); to see the results. Were you able to see what the resultant list looked like?

Comment: I tired again.  It was messy because of all the elements that did not have a date.  Not sure if I got is exactly right.  Wasn't sure which latest date you needed.  The results get ID 1 & 2.

Comment: I'm trying to display the whole document as a 'feed' in date order, so that, when displayed as text, they would appear:\n\n

Entry 2 date\n
Entry 2 details\n\n

Entry 1 date\n
Entry 1 details\n\n

Entry 3 date\n
Entry 3 details\n\n

At the moment, with my code, it displays as:\n\n

Entry 1 Date\n
Entry 1 Details\n\n

Entry 3 Date\n
Entry 1 details (partial - this is the point at which the string gets too long - the foreach loop isn't stopping after reading all elements)\n\n

Sorry if you get two notifications for this - I pressed enter early by accident

Comment: Finally got it right.  It was sorting by strings and the days '08' and '8' was causing sort to get wrong order.  So I cast to DateTime.  Also has to use SelectMany to group all elements together.

Comment: Despite the fact that there appears to be nothing wrong with the script and there are no compiler errors, it's telling me that I have to fix any compiler errors before the script can be loaded. I'll have to try and fiddle with it a bit more to see what's gone wrong. Sorry to have to ask so many questions, but did the results you got display as I mentioned in the previous comment?

Comment: I think the real issue with what I'm using is with the feedText+=. I just tried a different method, where the xml was modified to all be within one 'type' element, and it produced an endless stream of text. I can't think of another way to display it, though.

Comment: Maybe this :  XElement elements = new XElement("Document");
            elements.Add(results);

Comment: Ah, thank you. That works a treat. I worked it into my existing script because for some reason I still can't get yours to compile. I figured out that half the problems were coming from the fact that I was calling the function in Update rather than on Start. Did you want to update your answer to include your suggestion or should I post the solution in my code?

Comment: Don't care.  You should just be able to take my code for 'results' and replace 'doc' with  'xDocument'.  Rest of my code is just for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Use [XML Serialization](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Saving_and_Loading_Data:_XmlSerializer) for this purpose.